# How to automatically add !default to all SASS/SCSS variables

Tags: sass

To impmlement themes using SASS/SCSS we have `default.scss` file with global variables (and the default theme at the same time) where some variables are derived from the basic theme color. In SCSS theme file (`theme.scss`) loaded before `defaults.css` we always override the basic theme color and also override some variables specific to the theme. For omitted variables we expect that they will get values from the `defaults.scss` but if there is `$text-color = $basic-color` assignment then value of `$basic-color` should be taken from the theme, not the default one.

```scss
/* theme.scss... */
$base-color: green;
/* Some variables may be omitted in some themes 
   to use theme base-color by default.
   In this theme $text-color is expected to be green.
  $text-color: teal;
*/ 
$button-color: black;

/* default.scss */
$base-color: blue          !default;
$text-color: $base-color   !default;
$button-color: $base-color !default;
```

See this example at https://jsfiddle.net/ena66ag3/

It works fine but I don't wish to append `!default` to each line of `default.scss` as there are hundreds of lines and it makes it hard to read the values. Is there a way to make it automatically with some optiopns in the import directive or in the top of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no current support in sass to specify variable flags for multiple variables at once. They have to be added to each line, and that is the current best practice for declaring your theme defaults.

You can see that both [bootstrap (v4)](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss) and [foundation sites](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/blob/develop/scss/_global.scss) do it this way, as both are respectable frameworks built on Sass I would recommend going that route.

There is also no way to declare variables with dynamic variable names, so the only way to work around it at this point would be to have some preprocessing that appends the default flag to all the variables in your default file, but that is probably a bigger issue as it would hide rather important implementation details from anyone reading it.

If you still want to have the behavior of defaults without default flags with something that is supported by the language it would be using a map.

```
/*
 * In theme.scss
 */
$globals: (
  line-height: 10,             // theme value
  something-special: 'black',  // theme value
);

/* 
 * In defaults.scss
 */
// Ensure there is an empty globals map if no theme is loaded
$globals: () !default; 

// Merge theme defaults over the default values
$globals: map-merge((
  font-size: 1,      // default value
  line-height: 2,    // default value
), $globals);

/**
 * Usage
 */
div {
  font-size: map-get($globals, font-size);              // 1
  line-height: map-get($globals, line-height);          // 10
  border-radius: map-get($globals, something-special);  // black 
}
```

However I would **not** go with this as it leads to somewhat bizarre code for accessing basic theme variables. With the currently available options appending a default flag to all the lines is probably your best bet.